# "Other..." New user has been created and it wasn't me. (Monterey 12.4 ( 21F79))

Tags: macos, user-account, login, monterey, group

2 days ago when I turned on my machine I found this screen:
("Otra...") means other in English, sorry but it's all in Spanish. When I go to check in the dictionary utility if the root user is activated, I confirm that it is not, anyway I activate it again, I change the password again, and I deactivate it again, this did not work, it does not work either to do with the "guest user", I have already formatted the entire system and I have done a clean reinstall of the operating system from scratch. But the problem persists, my head begins to formulate strange theories about an application or someone remotely creating that user with root privileges, I read some old posts about it but we are talking about Yosemite, by the way the version of the operating system is: [Monterey 12.4 ( 21F79)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PuVP.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PuVP.png)
I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on what is happening on my login screen.

**EDIT)** As I said before, the root user was always disabled and I checked it numerous times, the code proposed by ICONDAEMON worked, in fact, the user “Other…” disappeared, I mean this code:`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE`. But the feeling that this gives me is that this user was simply hidden, it's chilling, I would like to know how that user was created, thanks for your contributions
[image]

**EDIT2)** `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool TRUE` - for example, in the opposite way, if I use the term TRUE, the user “OTHER…” reappears, therefore this code is not to eliminate that user definitively, but rather to hide it, it is chilling –

When I go to “Dictionary Utility”, under “services”, two options appear: 1-Active directory and 2-LPAPv3. This is ok? –

Comment: You've posted additions to your question below, where we usually expect the answers to be. Can you please **edit** your quesition with relevant details?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable and disable the root user, you are causing this to show up. The system is trying to be helpful and make it possible for that disabled user to log in, not that [any of the dozens of accounts that come with the system even have a log in shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/422801/5472) for ssh.

You are seeing all the mechanisms for remote managed users, not evidence that they are configured or enabled.

For us to help further, what is the id of this new user that was created? Do you have a specific home folder, specific account?

Comment: this. what id has “other…”? If you click this on the login screen it does take you to a login + password screen, doesn’t it? There is really nothing “chilling” going on here. 

Comment: Other exists to specify a new, never been logged in account in cases of external directories @slartibartfast it doesn’t mean that any user has ever logged in that way, it opens the door before the first user can be set up as well as keeps the door open afterwards for them.

Comment: without any user credentials you can login using “Other…” as user name and any password?

Comment: That’s not what I intended to say at all @slartibartfast - it just pops up a user field and a password field to which you can type anything. Whether there’s an auth chain or tool that accepts that credential depends on your setup. If you have a different question - go ahead and ask it as a full question, please. I agree there’s nothing chilling or compromised here at all - perfectly normal setup AFAIK.